# How to sum two arrays in another array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sum

I want to try to get two arrays and sum them to another array, but it just doens't work, and I don't know why.

**My code :**

```
int v1[3],v2[3],v3[3];

for(int i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("Type a number : \n");
    scanf("%d", &v1[i]);
}

for(int i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("Type a number : \n");
    scanf("%d", &v2[i]);
}

for(int i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
 v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
 scanf("%d", &v3[i]);

 printf("Total : %d ", &v3[i]);
}
```

And when I get to type all the 6 numbers, he just don't show Total, and I have to type more to go to exit screen.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a scanf for the result array? ("scanf("%d", &v3[i]);")

Comment: I just wanted to show the result for the user. But as I am new to C, I am newbie to this stuff.

Comment: Read the answers more carefully.

Comment: The final result continue being the same as from the old code, I don't know what is happening. Even if I put the printf out of the for or inside and with the modifications that the answers said, it's the same result.

Comment: Your main problem here is that you either compiled your program with no warnings enabled or that you ignored the warning(s).

Comment: So if the input is `1 2 3 4 5 6`, you want the output `5 7 9` ?

Comment: Please note that there really wasn't a need for the screen shot.  You should have copied and pasted the text in the screen shot directly into the question, indented as 'code' (select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit window to indent it), and possibly add `<!-- language: lang-none -->` above it on an unindented line of its own with a blank line above and below.

Comment: @4386427 Exactly, is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you exactly want? Summation of each element from two arrays into a new third array? That's it right?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int v1[3],v2[3],v3[3];

    for(int i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
      printf("Type a number for v1 :\t");
      scanf("%d", &v1[i]);

      printf("Type a number for v2 :\t");
      scanf("%d", &v2[i]);
      // Add here
      v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i]; // Mind you that this could lead to integer overflow.
  }

  printf("\nResult Arr :\n");
  for(int i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%d\n", v3[i]);
}
```

Comment: It worked the code, thanks. But as I am new to C, I don't know what that /t means. Could you explain to me, please ?

Comment: And what this (int argc, char** argv) will do ? Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: The `int main(int argc, char **argv)` is the form for the `main()` function when you use command line arguments.  This code doesn't use command line arguments; the main function should be defined using `int main(void)` to indicate that it is ignoring any command line arguments.  The `\t` (note the backslash, not forward slash `/t`) is a tab.  That's covered in any basic book on C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for explaning to me, I started to learn C almost 3 months ago, so a lot of things are new to me.

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of scanf inside the third for loop?

I think remove `scanf` inside third for loop:

```
 scanf("%d", &v3[i]);
```

Also, remove `&` in printf:

```
printf("Total : %d ", v3[i]);
```

**Full code:** This code working fine on **GCC** compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int v1[3],v2[3],v3[3], i;

        for(i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
        {
                printf("Type a number : \n");
                scanf("%d", &v1[i]);
        }

        for(i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
        {
                printf("Type a number : \n");
                scanf("%d", &v2[i]);
        }

        for(i  = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
        {
                v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];

                printf("Total : %d\n", v3[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: It does not work the same way, because the end result does not have the actual sum of the two vectors.

Comment: @Novatec: your code didn't show that calculation, nor did the question mention it.  Changing the rules isn't fair — in extreme cases, the question becomes a 'chameleon question', and they're bad.

Comment: Arguably, the code should check the return value from each of the surviving `scanf()` calls.  But your basic diagnosis is correct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am sorry for what I did here, your code too works, thanks for helping me. I am new to C, so for me, the third scanf would read the third array and would work, but as it seems, it don't. Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the third scanf and you don't want the ampersand before the v3 in the printf.

Comment: It does not work the same way, because the end result does not have the actual sum of the two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize your array so you won't have a garbage.

```
`int v1[3] = {0,0,0}, v2[3] = {0,0,0}, v3[3] = {0,0,0};`
```

in adding both arrays,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    printf("total: %d", v3[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store result in v3, you need to remove `scanf("%d", &v3[i]);` from last loop

You need to change

```
printf("Total : %d ", &v3[i]);//you are passing address here, where printf expects value
```

to

```
printf("Total : %d ", v3[i]);
```

Also you should add a space before %d in each scanf so that it takes care of enter hit from previous input
eg

```
scanf(" %d", &v1[i]);
```

Comment: Is still showing  Total : 6487568. Even after I removed the scanf, why is that happening ? If I let &v3[i] he just show that, and If I remove, he shows the Total as 2.

Comment: You need to remove & from printf as well

Comment: It does not work the same way, because the end result does not have the actual sum of the two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you added a scanf function in the last for loop which does the summation.
So if you just remove that scanf line it will work great.
Old code:

```
int v1[3],v2[3],v3[3]; for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) { printf("Type a  number : \n"); scanf("%d", &v1[i]); } for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {  printf("Type a number : \n"); scanf("%d", &v2[i]); } for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) { v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i]; scanf("%d", &v3[i]);    printf("Total : %d ", &v3[i]); }
```

New code should be

```
int v1[3],v2[3],v3[3]; for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) { printf("Type a number : \n"); scanf("%d", &v1[i]); } for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) { printf("Type a number : \n"); scanf("%d", &v2[i]); } for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) { v3[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];  printf("Total : %d ", &v3[i]); }
```

That should do it.

Comment: It does not work the same way, because the end result does not have the actual sum of the two vectors.